# Redis and Postgresql synchronization (online users status)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, import, redis, synchronization

In an NodeJS application I have to maintain a "who was online in the last N minutes" state. Since there is potentially thousands of online users - for performance reasons - I decided to not update my Postgresql `user` table for this task.

I choosed to use Redis to manage the online status. It's very easy and efficient.

But now I want to make complex queries to the `user` table, **sorted by** the online status.

I was thinking of creating a `online` table filled every minute from a Redis snapshot, but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Following the table filling, will the next query referencing the `online` table take a big hit caused by the new indexes creation or loading?

Does anyone know a better solution?

Comment: What kind of complex queries?

Comment: There is a redis foreign data wrapper for PostgreSQL - https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw I used it for one of our applications and generally it worked OK. But there are always some limitations for queries - regarding conditions it can translate and use on counter part. So you could encounter it here too. Another FDW even allows writes into redis - https://github.com/nahanni/rw_redis_fdw

Comment: Plus another note - as you most likely know - probably better then me :-) - redis behaves differently than PG regarding transactions and isolation levels. So using FDW you could see some minor inconsistences in data selected from redis.

Comment: There is relations between users (friend, blocked, ...) so a query could be "show me users having such qualities, sorted by online status and discard users who blocked me".

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve almost this exact same issue, but I took a different approach because I Didn't like the issues caused by trying to mix Redis and Postgres.

My solution was to collect the online data in a queue (Zero MQ in my case) but any queueing system should work, or a stream processing facility like Amazon Kinesis (The alternative I looked at.) I then inserted the data in batches into a second table (not the users table). I don't delete or update that table, only inserts and queries are allowed.

Doing things this way preserved the ability to do joins between the last online data and the users table without bogging down the database or creating many updates on the user tables. It has the side effect of giving us a lot of other useful data.

One thing to note that I have though about when thinking of other solutions to this problem is that your users table in transactional data(OLTP) while the latest online information is really analytics data (OLAP), so if you have a data warehouse, data lake, big data, or whatever term of the week you want to use for storing this type of data and querying against it that may be a better solution.